# Understanding an array of pointers to an object in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

There are 3 types of planes.

- A nA321 which has a max capacity of 10 containers
- nB777 which has a max capacity of 32 containers
- nB787 which has a max capacity of 40 containers

I want to index through the list and create an Airplane object and store the respective value. My for loop will create a new Airplane object that is set to 10. How can I dynamically set the respective plane types to the corresponding max capacity? The code currently outputs the address, for example:

Airplane 1 maximum load 0xffe

I am trying to print the following:

```
Airplane 1 maximum load 10
Airplane 2 maximum load 10
Airplane 3 maximum load 10
Airplane 4 maximum load 10
Airplane 5 maximum load 32
Airplane 6 maximum load 32
Airplane 7 maximum load 40
```

My code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Airplane
{
    public:
        Airplane(int n); // the maximum capacity of the airplane
        int maxLoad(void) const;
        int currentLoad(void) const;
        bool addContainers(int n);
    private:
        const int maxContainers;
        int numContainers;
};

Airplane::Airplane(int n):maxContainers(n){
    n = maxContainers;
}

int Airplane::maxLoad(void) const{
    return maxContainers;
}

int Airplane::currentLoad(void) const{
    return numContainers;
}

class Airline
{
    public:
        Airline(int nA321, int nB777, int nB787);
        ~Airline(void);
        void addShipment(int size);
        void printSummary(void) const; // prints a list of airplanes with their current and maximum load.
    
    private:
        const int nAirplanes; // total # of airplanes used by airline
        Airplane** airplaneList; // array of pointers to Airplane objects
};
  
Airline::Airline(int nA321, int nB777, int nB787):nAirplanes(nA321 + nB777 + nB787){
    airplaneList = new Airplane*[nAirplanes];
    for ( int i = 0; i < this->nAirplanes; i++ ){
        airplaneList[i] = new Airplane(10);
        airplaneList[i] -> maxLoad();
        cout << "Airline " << i+1 << " maximum load " << airplaneList[i] << endl;
    }
}

Airline::~Airline(void){}

int main(void)
{
    // create an Airline with 4 A321, 2 B777 and 1 B787
    Airline airline(4,2,1);
    cout << "Assignment complete" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Use `cout ... airplaneList[i]->maxLoad();`. Explanation: `airplaneList` is a pointer to an array of `Airplane` pointers. So `airplaneList[i]` will be an `Airplane` pointer. So you need to dereference it, with `(*airplaneList[i]).maxLoad()` or `airplaneList[i]->maxLoad()`. Does it make sense?

Comment: That makes sense! It is printing the value now, but how can I dynamically set the respective airplane type to the corresponding max capacity? I know I can set up 3 for loops, but doesn't seem like the cleanest approach

Comment: @Alex looks like 3 `for` loops IS a cleanesn approach in this case

Comment: Unrelated: [Avoid `new` as much as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new). If the option is available to you on this assignment, prefer to use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)s. You will have significantly fewer memory management woes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use runtime polymorphism:

- Make your `Airplane` class virtual pure, so you cannot really instantiate an `Airplane`.

```
    virtual int maxLoad() const = 0;
```

- Add 3 subclasses to your `Airplane` class, one for each type of plane. These subclasses will define the maximum number of containers, for example, using an `static inline const` member.

```
    static inline const int maxContainers{10};
```

They will also implement the `maxLoad` virtual method to return `maxContainers`.

```
    virtual int maxLoad() const override { return maxContainers; }
```

- For each airline, keep the `airplaneList` as an array of `Airplane*`, but then assign a specific plane instance to each of those pointers:

```
    airplaneList = new Airplane*[nAirplanes];
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nA321; i++, size++) { airplaneList[size] = new A321(); }
    for (int i = 0; i < nB777; i++, size++) { airplaneList[size] = new B777(); }
    for (int i = 0; i < nB787; i++, size++) { airplaneList[size] = new B787(); }
```

- And two important points regarding destructors:

1. Make `Airplane` destructor virtual.
    Since `airplaneList` is an array of `Airplane` pointers created through `new`, at some point we should do a `delete` of each of those pointers, and that is going to invoke the `Airplane` destructor; however, since we actually created instances of subclasses of `Airplane` (e.g. with `new A321()`), we need the destructor of the subclass to be executed.
    That won't be possible if the `Airplane` destructor is not virtual.

```
    virtual ~Airplane() {};
```

2. `Airline` constructor is doing a `new[]` for the airplane list, and a `new` for each airplane. `Airline` destructor should do the correspondings `delete[]` and `delete`.

```
Airline::~Airline()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nAirplanes; i++) { delete airplaneList[i]; }
    delete[] airplaneList;
}
```

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/YzqPWE1vb)

```
// Outputs:
//
//   Airplane 1 (A321): maximum load = 10
//   Airplane 2 (A321): maximum load = 10
//   Airplane 3 (A321): maximum load = 10
//   Airplane 4 (A321): maximum load = 10
//   Airplane 5 (B777): maximum load = 32
//   Airplane 6 (B777): maximum load = 32
//   Airplane 7 (B787): maximum load = 40
//   Assignment complete
```

---

As an aside note, using a `std::vector` for the `airplaneList`, and smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`) to the airplane instances would simplify the code a lot:

- You wouldn't need the heap allocation for the airplane list.
- You wouldn't need to care about deleting the heap instances for the airplanes and the airplane list.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/E6ncE8KbY)

```cpp
class Airline
{
public:
    Airline(int nA321, int nB777, int nB787);
    ~Airline() {}
    void addShipment(int size);
    void printSummary(void) const; // prints a list of airplanes with their current and maximum load.

private:
    int nAirplanes{}; // total # of airplanes used by airline
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Airplane>> airplaneList{}; // array of pointers to Airplane objects
};
  
Airline::Airline(int nA321, int nB777, int nB787)
: nAirplanes(nA321 + nB777 + nB787)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < nA321; i++) { airplaneList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<A321>()); }
    for (auto i = 0; i < nB777; i++) { airplaneList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B777>()); }
    for (auto i = 0; i < nB787; i++) { airplaneList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B787>()); }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < airplaneList.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout
            << "Airplane " << i+1
            << " (" << airplaneList[i]->getName() << ")"
            << ": maximum load = " << airplaneList[i]->maxLoad() << "\n";
    }
}
```